# Уроки по php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Посоветуйте видео уроки по PHP, а то перерыл много сайтов, так и не нашел почти. Нашел только 1-ного нормального автора, но у него это еще в процессе, то есть всего 20 уроков отснято, а теперь тупик. (

Comment: Не могу представить видео уроки по языку программирования, честно... Лучше книги с примерами, все равно ничего нет, так что ищите книгу нормальную. Советую самоучитель пхп от издательства Питер.

Comment: Зря вы так, ребята, про видео уроки говорите. Полроссии по вебинарам учится. Так что видео - это хорошее дело! Минус только один - нельзя спросить у преподавателя что-либо.

У меня очень много сборников такого видео. Если у вас есть какой-нибудь сервер на хостинге, дайте доступ по фтп, залью. Или может у вас IP внешний и скорость инета хорошая.
А то у меня скорость позволяет, да только вот IP "серый".

Answer (score 1):

Я повторюсь так как в Сети уже есть ответы на данный вопрос. Очень хорошая книга КОТЕРОВ+ИсХодники( пришлось поискать нашел бесплатно) . Это книга помоагет развивать навыки php  очень хорошо освещена тема строковых функций. Книга очень интересная. Конечно это не видеокурс где все ну совсем разжевано. Прийдется запускать IDE и практиковатся за чашкой кофе;)

Answer (score 0):

Вот что смотрел я: PHP+MySQL Уроки. "Все Технические Моменты Онлайн Бизнеса в Видеоформате 2". Поделитесь тем что вы нашли.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже считаю, что видео уроки мало чем помогут. А вот сайты с готовыми примерами вполне. Вот [один](http://webscript.ru/) из них.
Если что, могу еще несколько ссылок сбросить.

Answer (score 0):

Бросьте! Вы что? Изучать язык программирования по видео урокам этот как серпом по яйцам. [Вот](http://habrahabr.ru/) есть ресурс, там вы найдете все что нужно с готовыми, разжеванными примерами.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите научиться программировать, то не для вас видеокурсы гуру Попова. Книги самое то: [литература](http://web-program-begin.blogspot.com/2011/08/blog-post_23.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.infospir.ru/ Уроки Евгения Харина